# Split string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to get the value of `caller_id` from the following string with JavaScript

```
{"dispnumber": "+XXXXXXXXXX", "extension": "1", "callid": "b7d14b81-68cf-4250-b5f2-fe486ef7b0b6", "destination": "+911762503777", "caller_id": "+91XXXSSSSSS", "action": "phone", "event": "connected"}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: 9'501 results with: Split string in Javascript

Comment: from the following string? or from the following object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data what you have shown looks like a valid JSON data. Just parse it like this

```
var obj = JSON.parse(string_data);
```

which will give you a valid JavaScript object and then you can get the `caller_id` property like this

```
console.log(obj.caller_id);
# +91XXXSSSSSS
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    // if it is javscript object 
    var obj = {"dispnumber": "+XXXXXXXXXX", "extension": "1", "callid": "b7d14b81-68cf-4250-b5f2-fe486ef7b0b6", "destination": "+911762503777", "caller_id": "+91XXXSSSSSS", "action": "phone", "event": "connected"};
    obj.caller_id;//+91XXXSSSSSS

    // if it is string
    var str = '{"dispnumber": "+XXXXXXXXXX", "extension": "1", "callid": "b7d14b81-68cf-4250-b5f2-fe486ef7b0b6", "destination": "+911762503777", "caller_id": "+91XXXSSSSSS", "action": "phone", "event": "connected"}';
    var obj = JSON.parse(str);
    obj.caller_id;//+91XXXSSSSSS
```

Answer (score 0):

We can assign the string to the variable and it treats as objects. Using objectname.keyname i.e (json.caller_id), we can get the value.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script> 
      var json = {"dispnumber": "+XXXXXXXXXX", "extension": "1", "callid": "b7d14b81-68cf-4250-              b5f2-fe486ef7b0b6","destination": "+911762503777", "caller_id": "+91XXXSSSSSS", "action": "phone", "event": "connected"};
      alert(json.caller_id);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

We can also get the value by  making it string and using JSON.parse converts into object

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script> 
      var obj = '{"dispnumber": "+XXXXXXXXXX", "extension": "1", "callid": "b7d14b81-68cf-4250-              b5f2-fe486ef7b0b6","destination": "+911762503777", "caller_id": "+91XXXSSSSSS", "action": "phone", "event": "connected"}';
      var json = JSON.parse(obj);
      alert(json.caller_id);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```